# Is there a way (or plugin) to find out how much CPU each thread is taking while debugging with IntelliJ?

Tags: multithreading, intellij-idea, profiling, cpu

I'm debugging a program within IntelliJ and need to see how much CPU each thread is consuming.

I do using jvmtop but I need to manually run it with the process ID each time I stop and start the program.

Is there any way to do it automatically? (preferably through some mechanism in IntelliJ or a plugin, though a script would be fine too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Java profiler, such as [YourKit](http://yourkit.com), can show this information to you. You'll need to run the profiler separately; there is no profiler that integrates directly into the UI of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Bummer :(

Perhaps at least a way to run jvmtop in the IntelliJ terminal window in a click of a button without having to manually look up and input the debugged process pid?